# No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Tags: spring-mvc, postman

So, while i was dealing with RestApi and trying to GET a request form POSTMAN , this throws an error stating

> No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type
> 'null'

I was expecting the requestmapping will return a list of array in json data format.

here is my code below.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/postman")
public class PostManController {
    @Autowired
    private PostmanProductDao postmanProductDao;
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value = "/hi")
    public String showPostman(){
        return "Hey, I am the postman. the new Buddy.";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping (value = "/Products",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<PostmanProduct> getProducts(){
        return this.postmanProductDao.getProducts();
    }
}

@Component
public class PostmanProductDao {

    List<PostmanProduct> list;

    public postmanProductDao(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new postmanProduct(100,"Ipod","Apple"));
        list.add(new postmanProduct(102,"Samsung Buds","Samsung"));
    }

    public List<PostmanProduct> getProducts(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing @Controller annotation is this expected or typo?

Comment: this is a typo. I have attahed @Restcontroller there.

Comment: You are missing `content-type` header while sending the request hence the case

Comment: @Harsh I tried that too. I gave content-type : application/json. However the main issue was the jackson core dependency version.

Answer (score 0):

So adding this dependecny resolved the issue. There was an issue with the version 2.13.4.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I believe, if its a spring boot project, this dependency does not need to be added externally, it works as is !

Comment: No. I was dealing with spring core with Maven dependency.